# What's the possible reason for this IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, spring, illegalargumentexception, type-mismatch

I'm trying to update a value via PUT request. There seems to be an IllegalArgumentException/TypeMismatchException which I can't seem to figure out why.

**Here's the *Product* model class:**

```
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private String vendor;
    private String description;
    private Boolean returnPolicy;
```

**Here's the ProductController code for PUT method:**

```
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/products/{id}")
public void updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable int id) {
    res = productService.updateProduct(product, id);
    System.out.println(res ? "Successful" : "Unsuccessful");
}
```

**Here's the updateProduct method for updating the product:**

```
public Boolean updateProduct(Product product, int id) {
    if(productRepository.findById(Integer.toString(id)) != null) {
        productRepository.save(product);
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

**Here's my ProductRepository class:**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import testing.poc.models.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, String>{

}
```

**This is the URL for my PUT request via Postman:**

> http://localhost:8080/products/8

**This is the entry in the DB that I'm trying to update:**
[image: entry]

The message I'm getting is as follows:

> {
>       "timestamp": "2019-03-27T13:53:58.093+0000",
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "message": "Provided id of the wrong type for class testing.models.Product. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class testing.models.Product. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String",
>       "path": "/products/8"
>   }

and

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class testing.models.Product. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String

I don't understand how a String type is being supplied when I've declared 'id' as int everywhere. How can this be fixed?

Comment: `Integer.toString(id)` converts your `int` into a `String` . Could you add your `ProductRepository` class ?

Comment: Integer.toString(id) - I've done this within the method because findById requires a String parameter. 
Added the ProductRepository class in the edit.

Comment: Change to " public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>" and remove the Integer.toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let us see `ProductRepository` declaration, I assume `findById` method is wrong since it has a String as first parameter, but `ProductRepository` has Integer as @Id.

Change `ProductRepository` like below

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import testing.poc.models.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your repository to a `CrudRepository<Product, Integer>` , the second parameter must be the type of the ID of the entity.